# Creating zod schema for generic interface

Tags: typescript, runtime, zod

I've got this generic interface for paginated response:

```
export interface PaginatedResponse<T> {
  pageIndex: number;
  pageSize: number;
  totalCount: number;
  totalPages: number;
  items: Array<T>;
}
```

And then I want to turn it in zod schema for runtime type checks.
The approach was like this:

```
const PaginatedResponseSchema = z.object({
  pageIndex: z.number(),
  pageSize: z.number(),
  totalCount: z.number(),
  totalPages: z.number(),
  items: z.array(???), // <=
});

export type PaginatedResponse<T> = z.infer<typeof PaginatedResponseSchema>;
```

What type of array should be items in the schema?

Comment: Fun fact: I was trying to do the exact same thing as you when I came to this google result.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can create a generic function that returns a new schema given a schema for the `items` field. So for example you could write:

```js
function createPaginatedResponseSchema<ItemType extends z.ZodTypeAny>(
  itemSchema: ItemType,
) {
  return z.object({
    pageIndex: z.number(),
    pageSize: z.number(),
    totalCount: z.number(),
    totalPages: z.number(),
    items: z.array(itemSchema),
  });
}
```

[This section in the `zod` docs goes into more specifics](https://github.com/colinhacks/zod#writing-generic-functions) about generic functions.

Comment: Is it also possible, to then create a type, using infer, with that createSchema function?

Comment: Should be `const schema = createPaginatedResponseSchema(z.string())` and then
`type Schema = z.infer<typeof schema>`