# ZOD type infer not working as expected when generic schema

Tags: typescript, generics, zod

I just recently looked into ZOD, trying to replace many of my interfaces with schemas and then using the `z.infer` to get a type instead.

This has worked fine, with simpler types, but I am encountering behaviour I do not understand when using generic schemas.

Information sources:

- https://github.com/colinhacks/zod#writing-generic-functions
- [Creating zod schema for generic interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74907523/creating-zod-schema-for-generic-interface)

My main problem is that `z.infer` seems to return the zod types instead of the inferred type when generic type information is given (e.g. returns `ZodString` instead of `string`)

**Below a simplified version of my problem**

I have a generic schema that returns a value using a simple lookup object:

```
const MainDish = <T extends Recipe>(type: T) =>
  z.object({
    drink: z.literal('water'),
    name: z.string(),
    ingredients: z.nativeEnum(RecipeIngredientsLookup[type]), // Removing this leads to no zod types after infer
  });

  type MainDishType<T extends Recipe> = z.infer<ReturnType<typeof MainDish<T>>>; // Infer Type from ZOD schema
```

In comparison a similar typescript interface for comparison purpose

```
  interface OtherDish<T extends Recipe>{ // Write type as interface
    drink:'water',
    name:string,
    ingredient: keyof typeof RecipeIngredientsLookup[T]
  }
```

And now generic class / component trying to use both types:

```
class Restaurant<T extends Recipe> {
  public thisIsInterface: OtherDish<T> ={
    name: 'Unknown Dish Name',
    drink: 'water',
    ingredient: undefined,
  }

  public thisHasZodTypes: MainDishType<T> ={
    name: 'Unknown Dish Name',
    drink: 'water',
    ingredients:undefined,
  }

  public thisHasNoZodTypes: MainDishType<Recipe.TomatoSoup> ={
    name: 'Tomato Soup',
    drink: 'water',
    ingredients:TomatoSoupIngredients.Tomato,
  }

  constructor(){
    if(this.thisIsInterface.name)
    // this.thisIsInterface.name is not optional

    if(this.thisHasZodTypes.name)
    // this.thisIsInterface.name is optional and not string type <-- Why?

    if(this.thisHasNoZodTypes.name)
    // this.thisIsInterface.name is string type but still otional  <-- Why?
  }
}
```

I know that it is not possible for the class to properly create an object since it is still unclear what `T` is going to be, but I would have expected that `z.infer` would behave equal with a generic schema as it does with a generic typescript interface.

In my project I am using the inferred zod schema as type for my FormGroup / FormControl (Angular), this is not working properly due to the ZodTypes. It is working fine when there are primitive types (e.g. using the `OtherDish<T>`)

[Full Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-65caiv?file=index.ts)

**Questions:**

- Why are all my properties optional in the inferred zod types?
- Why is the generic zod schema type not inferring the types correctly (`name` is `ZodString` instead of `string`)?
- How can I achieve the same type structure from my ZOD schema keeping the flexibility of the generic type?

I am not sure if these are limitations of ZOD or if I am doing something wrong.

Thanks in advance!